# Perl string comparison

Tags: perl

I have a basic problem with chain comparison in Perl.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $toto ="a";

if ("a" cmp $toto)
{
    print "success";
}
else
{
    print "fail\n";
}

my $titi=<STDIN>;
```

It always says `fail`.

If I use `eq` rather than `cmp`, it works.

But if I do:

```
my $toto = <STDIN>;

if ("a" eq $toto)
{
    print "success";
}
else
{
    print "fail\n";
}

my $titi=<STDIN>;
```

And I use `a` as input, this prints `fail`.

What is wrong ?

Comment: When in doubt: `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print Dumper $toto;`.

Comment: What do you mean by *chain* comparison?

Answer (score 3):

#### What is the `cmp` operator?

`$a cmp $b` yields the lexicographic relation between `$a` and `$b`, which means that it returns three values:

- **-1** meaning `$a` is less than `$b`
- **0** meaning `$a` is equal to `$b`
- **1** meaning `$a` is larger than `$b`

```
$a = "a";
$b = "a";

print ($a cmp $b);
```

Outputs **0**, meaning they are equal

---

#### Reading from `STDIN`

```
my $toto = <STDIN>;
```

When you use something like this to read a single line from `STDIN` (i.e. reading in scalar context) it will read the entire line, including the linefeed.

This means that `$toto` is `"a\n"` and not just `"a"`, which is why your latter use of `eq` fails.

You can fix the issue by using `chomp`, which will remove the linefeed character from `$toto`, like this

#### snippet.pl

```
my    $toto = <STDIN>;
chomp $toto;

if ( $toto eq "a" ) {
   print "Yes!\n";
}
```

An example run would look like this

```
$ perl snippet.pl
a<return>
Yes!
```

Comment: @Sobrique he is not reading from `<STDIN>` in the part where he says `eq` works, read the section on `cmp` one more time and look over *OP*s code (and what he has written).

Comment: I was thinking more specifically - `cmp` and `eq` are opposite logic values. Even if he `chomp`s, `cmp` will still be "false", because it'll return `0`.

Comment: @Sobrique I never said that he should use `cmp` to compare for equality in the latter case.

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp: Just as you can't write to `print STDOUT`, you can't read from `<STDIN>` because it isn't a file handle

Answer (score 1):

**cmp** is the comparison operator, which is mostly useful for sorting strings. This operator is documented in `perldoc perlop`.

> Binary "cmp" returns -1, 0, or 1 depending on whether the left
>   argument is  stringwise less than, equal to, or greater than the right
>   argument.

For example:

```
bash$ perl -e 'print sort { $a cmp $b } qw( y z x); print "\n"'
xyz
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out **perldoc perlop** equality operators:

> Binary "eq" returns true if the left argument is stringwise equal to the right argument.
>
> Binary "cmp" returns -1, 0, or 1 depending on whether the left argument is stringwise less than, equal to, or greater than the right argument.

Instead of `"a" cmp $toto` try `"a" eq $toto` or change your conditional statement to use **zero** as success

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working is because `cmp` isn't `eq`. They return different values on equality.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "fish";

print $string cmp $string;
print $string eq $string;
```

`eq` is `1` (true) if they match, and `0` (false) if they don't.
`cmp` returns -1 if it's before (true), `0` if equal (false) and `+1` if after. Specifically - this is used for sorting. (And it's counterpart `<=>` does the same thing, which perhaps is a bit more obvious it isn't comparing equality).

Net result is - you've accidentally inverted the logic of your program.

```
print "1 True","\n" if "fish2" cmp "fish3";
print "2 True","\n" if "fish2" cmp "fish2";
print "3 True","\n" if "fish2" cmp "fish1";
```

You could use `not` to negate the `cmp`, but really the answer is - use `eq` instead.

(Also - don't forget to `chomp` when you read `STDIN`).